# Unable to remove a Team Foundation Server collection

Tags: tfs

I have to switch to a new source control server. I'm trying to remove the old TFS collection with the Add/Remove Team Foundation Server, but the "Remove" button is disabled. How do I remove the old collection?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible, that you don't have sufficient permissions to detach the collection? Regarding to "[Move a Team Project Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd936138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#RequiredPermissions)" you have to be

- a member of the Administrators security group on the server or servers that are running the administration console for Team Foundation
- a member of the sysadmin group in SQL Server on the servers and instances that host databases for TFS
- a member of the Farm Administrators group for the farm to which you are configuring a Web application and changing settings for the collection, if your deployment uses SharePoint Products.